# How to build an arraylist from part of another one in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Now I have a sorted `ArrayList object listA`, and its size is about from 50 to 100. Now I want to build another ArrayList which just contains the first 30 elements in listA.

So how to write a code to achieve this.

I can write some code to do this, but I want to know the way with the minimum time cost.

Comment: *I can write some code to do this, but I want to know the way with the minimum time cost* first write your code, then we will help you.

Comment: you can use functions provided by the ArrayList...

Comment: We are not here for writing code for you. if you found some issue then SO welcomes to help you.So always write code first and then ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) and pass that into the new list's constructor (or call [`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)).

> I want to know the way with the minimum time cost.

Are you doing this hundreds of thousands of times in a loop? If so, a simple `for` loop may be better, but I'd wait until/unless I saw a real performance issue.

Comment: I knew something like this had to exist.  Thanks for the info!